# PDOException “could not find driver” with heroku, postgres and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have just installed Botman Studio with postgres, heroku, and PHP and I am receiving a PDOException could not find driver.

This is the specific line of code it is referring to:

PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\Telegram\Database\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:68

2   PDO::__construct("pgsql:host=ec2-23-21-65-173.compute-1.amazonaws.com;dbname=d6hea6nf02h1an;port=5432;sslmode=prefer", "dfgicaihxreswg", "ae947e0cfddd775f69aba8ffbf96e1a7b0e5d71a1749695c82642a01399bdea6", [])
      C:\Telegram\Database\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:68

Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Is this something to do with my PHP installation?

Searching the internet has not helped, all I get is experts-exchange and examples, but no solutions. My operating system is Windows.

Comment: No, this question is different, it is not resolved with that

Comment: I already solved it by uncommenting the lines from php.ini:




extension = pdo_pgsql
extension = pgsql